# Jquery get a part of ID

Tags: jquery, element

I have different elements with same id part:

```
<div id="post-32">
<div id="post-50">
<div id="post-80">
```

etc..

i need extract number of id post and add in div a new button with the  value equal to "number-post".

```
<div id="post-32">...</div>
<div class="myclass">
    <button value="32">click here</button>
</div>
```

I tried with this code but return me for each post, as many buttons as there are posts.

```
$("[id^='post-']").each(
    function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
        var r  = $('<button type="button" id="add" value"'+id+'" name="test">Entra</button>');
        $(".myclass").append(r);
    }
);
```

Comment: why not add a class...

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/713726/

Comment: In what way did your posted JavaScript fail, what did you expect it to do that it didn't do?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/713754/ ???

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/713988/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just whatever...

```js
$("[id^='post-']").each(
    function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
        var r  = $('<div class="myclass"><button type="button" id="add-'+id+'" value="'+id+'" name="test['+id+']">Entra</button><div>');
        $(this).prepend(r);
    }
);
```

```css
.myclass{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-32">The quick brown </div>
<div id="post-50">fox jumps over </div>
<div id="post-80">the lazy dog </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
$("[id^='post-']").each(
   function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
      var r  = $('<button type="button" id="add-' + id + '" value"'+id+'" name="test-' 
      + id + '">Entra</button>');
      $(this).append(r);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the solution is the following:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll( 'div[id^="post-"]' );
var myClassDiv = jQuery( document.querySelector( 'div.myclass' ) );

if ( 0 < divs.length && myClassDiv ) {
    divs.forEach(
        function ( item ) {
            var itemID = item.id.split('-')[1];
            var button = document.createElement('button');

            button.type = 'button';
            button.id = 'add'; // you should normally use a unique ID here.
            // button.id = 'add-' + itemID; in order to have a unique button ID
            button.value = itemID;
            button.name = 'test';
            button.innerText = 'Entra'

            myClassDiv.append( jQuery( button ) );
        }
    );
}
```